# jQuery bind function to ready or ajaxSuccess

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need to execute code on either `ajaxSuccess` or a reload of the page.

How do I bind both to document?

```
$(document).on("ready, ajaxSuccess", function() {
    //...
});
```

Above code doesn't work

Comment: there is no event `"ready, ajaxSuccess". just pass in "ready". Also, consider writing the handler as a function with a function name and passing it in parameter. Also, you will need to provide code related to your ajax calls for community to be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The preferred way to do `ready` (as per docs) is

```
$(function(){
  // dom is ready here
})
```

Other syntaxes are deprecated

---

`ajaxSuccess()` doesn't need the dom to be ready so you can put it anywhere since the document always exists

```
$( document ).ajaxSuccess(function( event, xhr, settings ) {...
$(function(){
  // dom is ready here
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function like this:

```
(function($) {
    //Your handler
    var myHandler = function(e, xhr, settings) {
        if (xhr) {
            alert("Hello world from Ajax");
        }
        alert("Hello World from both");
    }

    //Invoking your Handler on ready and ajaxSuccess
    $(myHandler);
    $(document).ajaxSuccess(myHandler);
})(jQuery);
```

- Basicly you create a common method and invoke them by different events
- Note, that the first `(function($) {...})(jQuery)` part is just for avoiding any conflicts.